# How to remove iframe from parent page using a function inside the iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have an iframe I put on a page using a bookmarklet, I want this iframe to close itself when I navigate to a certain page inside this iframe.

How to do that using JavaScript?

Note: iframe and container page are in different domains.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know you cannot remove the element from the DOM from the iframe's container unless it's the same domain if I'm understanding you properly due to cross-domain security policies.

If this were possible you could infiltrate bank sites and all, it'd be a mess.

Comment: so how this bookmarklet is doing it? http://www.kaboodle.com/zd/setup/setuphelp-firefox.html#kabbookmark

Comment: Doesn't the bookmarklet execute script code on the document directly instead of creating iframes? Meaning it's not subject to cross-domain policy issues.

Comment: Can you paste where it's creating frames? Are you sure it's not just setting the `src` of a `script` element?

Comment: yes and this script create an iframe called kabIframeId to hold pages

Comment: i didn't find, but how they are creating and adding this iframe to the page? :(

Comment: How are you sure it's an iframe? Are you inspecting it? If so provide a screenshot of said iframe code which it creates?

Comment: MM, the bookmarklet doesnt seem to do that for me. Do you have to have an account in order for it to do that?

Comment: regardless how they are adding this iframe, i got my answer from this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182027/close-iframe-cross-domain/2182058#2182058 please add this link to your answer to be a complete answer for my need, thanks a lot for your effort.

Comment: I think it'd be better if you answered yourself since you found it. Good find.

Answer (score 3):

Beside @meder answer and his comments [How to remove iframe from parent page using a function inside the iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033128/how-to-remove-iframe-from-parent-page-using-a-function-inside-the-iframe/3033152#3033152),

i found this answer [Close iframe cross domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182027/close-iframe-cross-domain/2182058#2182058)
  Which helped me too much to solve my problem.

**UPDATE**: I found that this solution is not working on IE, and i failed to find a solution for that :(

Answer (score 2):

it isn't possible due the so called 'same origin policy' ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy )

if it's within the same domain you can try

```
jQuery('iframe-selector').remove(); // remove iframe
jQuery('iframe-selector').contents().empty(); // remove the iframe content
jQuery('iframe-selector').removeAttr('src'); // remove the source-attribute from the iframe
jQuery('iframe-selector').attr('src', 'javascript:return false;'); // remove the iframe source
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do cross-domain scripting with Iframes.