# How to append element to parent body from an iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code in the iframe.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("body").append($("#ctap").html());
    });
</script>
```

I want to append **#ctap**'s html to parent body. How can I do that ?

Comment: This seems ok to me.  You did create a node with the id ctap, right?

Comment: You need to call for this content from the parent body.

Comment: What are the href URLs of the host page and the iframe?

Comment: @RobRaisch, just explain him what is all about :)

Comment: host page - http://fd.subins.com/notifications & iframe - http://subins.com/files/comp.php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try following piece of code inside document.ready

```
parent.$("body").append($("#ctap").html());
```

Comment: As easy as anything, Thanks a lot @aravind.udayashankara

Answer (score 0):

If the **parent body** you should have something like this:

```
var iFrame = $('#iframe_id');
var iContent = iFrame.contents().find("#ctap").html();
$("body").append( iContent );
```

Answer (score 0):

To be able to access the content of the host page from the iframe they must have exactly the same location (hostname and port) due to cross domain scripting restrictions.

See [How to remove iframe from parent page using a function inside the iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033128/how-to-remove-iframe-from-parent-page-using-a-function-inside-the-iframe?rq=1)