# How do I close an iframe from an onclick event inside the iframe?

Tags: php, javascript

I want to close an iframe by clicking a button inside that iframe and come back out to the parent page.

I have searched but could not get appropriate code.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: you can't close an iframe! but you need to navigate to another page.. window.top.location.href = "newlocation.htm"

Comment: You really can't put the button outside?

Comment: second what @graphox said. it'd be a simple `$("#iframe_id").remove()` jQuery call.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
function closeIframe() [
   var iframe = document.getElementById('someid');
   iframe.parentNode.removeChild(iframe);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to assign an id to your iframe, like `<iframe id="someid"...`

Then you need a function to remove the iframe:

```
<a href="javascript: window.parent.document.getElementById('someid').parentNode.removeChild(window.parent.document.getElementById('someid'))">Close</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

This was covered here: [Close iframe cross domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182027/close-iframe-cross-domain) using a much more flexible method which is cross-domain functional.

Answer (score 0):

I have something like this in button onclick function:

```
parent.location.reload();
```

I guess this may help you:

```
var theFrame=parent.getElementById("iframeId");  
theFrame.parentNode.removeChild(theFrame);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="window.parent.document.getElementById('someid').parentNode.removeChild(window.parent.document.getElementById('someid'))">Close</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

iframe are a tricky one but i've had my share of fun with them. when trying to access an iframe from the "top" document, you would use:

```
top.iFrameToClose = top.document.getElementById("myiFrame");
top.iFrameToClose.offsetParent.removeChild(top.iFrameToClose);
```

i hope that helped...

Answer (score 0):

Using the **PostMessage API**, an iframe can be closed from an onclick event inside the frame.

**Parent**

```
<script>
    window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
        console.log("Message received from the child: " + event.data); //Message received from child
    });
</script>
```

**Child iframe code**

```
<button id="sendMessage">Send Message to Parent</button>
<script>
    var button = document.querySelector("#sendMessage");
    button.addEventListener("click", function () {
        // Send `message` to the parent using the postMessage method on the window.parent reference.
        window.parent.postMessage('message', "*");
    });
</script>
```