# JS close an iframe within the iframe itself, like Stripe's embedded form (CROSS BROWSER)

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I am building an embedded form, similar to Stripe's one.

Here is the demo code.

```html
<form action="/charge" method="POST">
  <script
    src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
    data-key="pk_test_6pRNASCoBOKtIshFeQd4XMUh"
    data-amount="2000"
    data-name="Stripe.com"
    data-description="2 widgets"
    data-image="/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png"
    data-locale="auto">
  </script>
</form>

<h5>This button still works after close iframe within iframe.</h5>
<button onclick="alert('hi');">Alert</button>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sq5zs5rq/3/

I want to understand, how can Stripe's "close modal" (X) button, actually close the entire iframe and the remain webpage still works.

I went over this, but it won't work Cross browser.
[Close iframe cross domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182027/close-iframe-cross-domain)

I also tried to make the iframe body (display:none), but the entire website doesn't work unless you refresh the page.

Could someone explain or provide a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [postMessage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) to communicate between the iframe window and the parent window.

This is feasible because you control the code in both windows

Comment: I am looking into the postMessageAPI document. Thanks for your reference.

Comment: Now, I stuck at here. 

`Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('http://0.0.0.0:8888') does not match the recipient window's origin ('http://0.0.0.0:8000').`